# QGIS 3.34 error method Class Factory()

Tags: qgis

I installed OSGeo4S with QGIS 3.34.
When I open QGIS I have this error:

Failed to load plugin 'crayfish' due to error calling classFactory() method. See the message log (Python Error) for more details.

2023-11-10T20:37:51     CRITICAL    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/utente/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\crayfish\gui\plot_widget.py", line 38, in
import pyqtgraph
File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyqtgraph'

```
         During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
         
         Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 423, in _startPlugin
          plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
          File "C:\Users/utente/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\crayfish\__init__.py", line 29, in classFactory
          from .plugin import CrayfishPlugin
          File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:\Users/utente/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\crayfish\plugin.py", line 31, in 
          from .gui.plot_widget import CrayfishPlotWidget
          File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:\Users/utente/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\crayfish\gui\plot_widget.py", line 45, in 
          import pyqtgraph
          File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
          File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "", line 664, in _load_unlocked
          File "", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
          File "", line 259, in load_module
          File "C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\crayfish\gui\..\pyqtgraph-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pyqtgraph\__init__.py", line 204, in 
          from .graphicsItems.VTickGroup import *
          File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
          File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "", line 664, in _load_unlocked
          File "", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
          File "", line 259, in load_module
          File "C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\crayfish\gui\..\pyqtgraph-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\VTickGroup.py", line 7, in 
          from .. import functions as fn
          File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
          File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "", line 664, in _load_unlocked
          File "", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
          File "", line 259, in load_module
          File "C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\crayfish\gui\..\pyqtgraph-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pyqtgraph\functions.py", line 17, in 
          from . import debug
          File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
          File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "", line 664, in _load_unlocked
          File "", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
          File "", line 259, in load_module
          File "C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\crayfish\gui\..\pyqtgraph-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pyqtgraph\debug.py", line 11, in 
          from . import ptime
          File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
          File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "", line 664, in _load_unlocked
          File "", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
          File "", line 259, in load_module
          File "C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\crayfish\gui\..\pyqtgraph-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pyqtgraph\ptime.py", line 24, in 
          cstart = systime.clock() ### Required to start the clock in windows
         AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

Comment: Have you tried removing/disabling the plugin?